# Derren Brown: "Paying with paper". Assuming legitimacy, is this simply ideomotor suggestion?

Tags: social-psychology, conditioning, social-cognition

Illusionist Derren Brown's video "[Paying with Paper](http://youtu.be/dy75GtKsOAw)" supposedly demonstrates real-world instances whereby Brown pays for several items in cash: the rub being, the "cash" is ***blank*** paper.

It's quite obvious that the gesture of paying is done so as to coincide with verbal assurances such as (paraphrased) *"it's fine...take it...you'll feel better"*. I'm curious whether this is the primary means Brown utilises, especially given the failure with the hotdog vendor.

With the aforementioned questions in mind, is it all a moot point, given this quote from Brown?:

> ‘(I use) magic, suggestion, psychology, misdirection and showmanship
>   ...I happily admit cheating, as it’s all part of the game.  I hope
>   some of the fun for the viewer comes from not knowing what’s real and
>   what isn’t. I am an entertainer first and foremost’.

Comment: As I have pointed out in comments to many questions regarding TV and stage "hypnosis", the quote provided is exactly the point about these "demonstrations".  Stage hypnosis is not the same as therapeutic hypnosis, and the whole point of TV and stage hypnosis is the entertainment factor.  It can be all scripted and pre-arranged.